# How can I configure Apache to run Perl CGI scripts?

Tags: perl, apache, macos

I want to configure Apache web server to run CGI scripts on Mac OS x 10.5. I have already started Apache Web Server on Mac. What are the steps to make the Apache run the Perl scripts?

Comment: If you like the guys answer, why don't you accept it?

Comment: hey blockhead, i am new to stackoverflow, and does not understand how the protocol works exactly. But will now read it first. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type of scripts? CGI? FastCGI? mod_perl? The steps are different.

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html
- http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html
- http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/intro/start_fast.html

Comment: Hey David, My question was about CGI and your link solved my problem. I appreciate your help. Thanks.